# SQL ignore one field with DISTINCT but ORDER BY it

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have two SQL SELECT with UNION DISTINCT, one with data from a new Database and one from an old Database so in each SELECT I have a field that describes from which Database the data came.

A simplified Example code:

```
SELECT username, name, lastname, 1 AS DB
  From new_DB.users
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT username, name, lastname, 2 AS DB
  From old_DB.users
ORDER BY db, lastname, name ASC
```

Data output looks like this:

| username | name | lastname | DB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fmuster | Fiona | Muster | 1 |
| kroos | Kim | Roos | 1 |
| Mmuster | Max | Muster | 1 |
| kroos | Kim | Roos | 2 |
| Ysoroli | Yelda | Soroli | 2 |

My problem is:
That there is duplicated data in the output.
The data that shouldn't be in the output is the second kroos but I can't just remove the field DB because I have to show all results from new_DB(DB 1) at the top.

thx for your help
Kim

Comment: To explain why you have a problem here, ask yourself which DB record should be used for the ORDER BY for someone who is in both sets. As a human, I can infer you probably want to treat them as DB 1, but the computer isn't allowed to make that kind of inference.

Comment: If a user exists in both Databases it should only show the user from DB 1. But the results from DB1 should be output before the results from DB 2. Because of an extremely specific use case, this is a requirement. There are different users in both DB's and some are the same so all have to be shown but users in DB1 first. So that's my Problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out duplicate rows coming from `old_DB.users`:

```
SELECT username, name, lastname, 1 AS DB
FROM new_DB.users
UNION 
SELECT o.username, o.name, o.lastname, 2 AS DB
FROM old_DB.users o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM new_DB.users n
  WHERE (n.username, n.name, n.lastname) = (o.username, o.name, o.lastname)
)
ORDER BY db, lastname, name ASC;
```

Or, with aggregation:

```
SELECT username, name, lastname, MIN(DB) AS DB
FROM (
  SELECT username, name, lastname, 1 AS DB
  FROM new_DB.users
  UNION 
  SELECT username, name, lastname, 2 AS DB
  FROM old_DB.users 
) t
GROUP BY username, name, lastname
ORDER BY db, lastname, name ASC;
```